# jquery datepicker auto correct invalid date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a simple datepicker using jquery and I am looking for a way to auto correct when the user edit the selected date, for example if the user selected this date from the calendar 30-11-2021
and then if he edited the date to 31-11-2021 I want to keep the correct day 30, also the month if the user by mistake add more than 12 the code should keep the selected month.

is it possible to do this?

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
           $("#TextBox_from_date").datepicker({
               numberOfMonths: 1,
               dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
               onSelect: function (selected) {
                   $("#TextBox_to_date").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected)


               }
           });
```

Comment: As I understand you want to keep the old data after the user selects new data?

Comment: @ Robbie yes keep the old data when the new data is incorrect but if new data is correct change it

Comment: I would suggest that you prevent the User from Entering text in that case. Maybe a Button to bring up the calendar and it is stored where the User cannot modify the date manually, only via the Datepicker.